# Field required bean of type that could not be found. Error springboot API deploy to ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04

I've been struggling with the problem for several days and have not found any help so I would ask here.

I have program like this. If I test it in localhost in my local machine it works perfectly.The problem begins if add war into ubuntu 18.04 tomcat. 
I have tested Jar in same server and it works. Also tested Heroku deployment and also working there. Maybe I have problems with making war package Itellij or what could be the problem?

**Tomcat catalina.out error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field forestDataServicesInterface in forestData.me24Spring.ForestDataController required a bean of type 'forestData.me24Spring.services.ForestDataServicesInterface' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'forestData.me24Spring.services.ForestDataServicesInterface' in your configuration.

04-Jul-2019 15:54:26.679 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/me24Spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'forestDataController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'forestDataServicesInterface'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'forestData.me24Spring.services.ForestDataServicesInterface' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'forestData.me24Spring.services.ForestDataServicesInterface' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1655)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
        ... 32 more
04-Jul-2019 15:54:26.681 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.42/webapps/me24Spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/me24Spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
04-Jul-2019 15:54:26.682 INFO [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.42/webapps/me24Spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [3,522] ms
```

**package forestData.me24Spring.services** :

```
public interface ForestDataServicesInterface extends JpaRepository<ForestDataMaaamet, Integer> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.ff2", nativeQuery = true)
     List<ForestDataMaaamet> findAll();


     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.ff2 where iscorrect = true", nativeQuery = true)
     List<ForestDataMaaamet> findCorrectForestData();

}
```

**package forestData.me24Spring**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Me24SpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Me24SpringApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
     return builder.sources(ForestDataController.class);
  }
```

}

**package forestData.me24Spring.controller**:

```
@RestController
public class ForestDataController {

    @Autowired
    ForestDataServicesInterface forestDataServicesInterface;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ForestDataMaaamet> fetchAllForestData() {
        return forestDataServicesInterface.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.decimal4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>decimal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**Structure that I have**

```
src/
|__ main/
    └── java/
    |   |   
    |   |___forestData.me24Spring/
    |       |
    |       ├── configuration/
    |       |   └── WebSecurityConfig.java
    |       ├── model/
    |       |   └── ForestData.java
    |       ├── repository/
    |       |   |__ repo.java
    |       └── services/
    |       |   └── ForestDataServicesInterface.java
    |       |
    |       |___Me24SpringApplication.java
    |       |
    |       |__ForestDataController.java
    |       
    └── resources/
        └── application.properties
```

Comment: Add the @Component above  public interface ForestDataServicesInterface .

Comment: Add `@Repository` to `ForestDataServicesInterface`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the stereotype annotation in order for the springboot to recognize bean for auto wiring.  Use `@Repository` annotation on top of `ForestDataServicesInterface`.

```
@Repository
public interface ForestDataServicesInterface extends JpaRepository<ForestDataMaaamet, Integer> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.ff2", nativeQuery = true)
     List<ForestDataMaaamet> findAll();


     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.ff2 where iscorrect = true", nativeQuery = true)
     List<ForestDataMaaamet> findCorrectForestData();

}
```

You can use any of the below annotation but since your interface is a Repository, it is advised to use @Repository

1. @Component
2. @Repository
3. @Controller
4. @Service

Comment: Tested all of these but no result. I updated question error code, added the whole error message.